# Another question about the width of Khone Phapheng falls

Tags: measurements

In a [previous](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/25547/why-cant-i-measure-the-width-of-a-waterfall-on-google-maps/25553#25553) question I asked why I can't measure the width of Khone Phapheng Falls; and I found out from the comments that I didn't take this into account that Khone Phapheng Falls are sets of falls that all discharge water to the Mekong River.

Now I have another question about the same falls:

[image: Khone]

I found the westernmost fall of the system to be Sopheakmit Fall and Khone Phahpheng itself being the easternmost fall. I measured their distance and it turned out to be $6.7$ miles which equals to $10783$ meters that is reported as the width of the system of falls.

But is it okay to measure the width of falls in this way? I mean even the rocks are included here! Shouldn't we just measure the width of each fall and then sum the numbers up to find the total width of the system?

In the latter way the width is measured very less and it would be Victoria Falls that becomes the widest falls in the world instead of Khone Phapheng.

Also, look at this picture which is from the answer on my previous question about the same falls:

[image: Khone]

This is the complete system of falls in the Khone Phapheng. But as I said before the $10783$ meters width is from one edge of the easternmost fall to the edge of the wesrernmost fall and it includes the rocks between them. So is 10783 meters a correct number? Shouldn't we calculate the width of the system by summing up the widths of all falls?

Comment: Why not [Victoria Falls](https://whc.unesco.org/en/list/509/#:~:text=Criterion%20(vii)%3A%20The%20Mosi,98%20m%20(Eastern%20Cataract).)?

Comment: Oh yes, Victoria Falls are wider than Niagara Falls. I will edit my question.

Comment: One strong rainfall runoff may change the channels. So why bother?